# IOS Write plugin at phonegap 2.9.1

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova

There is a guide how to create a plugin for phonegap 2.9.1 step by step, without the use nodejs?

thanks.

Comment: do you install phonegap on your system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will walk you through the first of a few steps in creating a custom PhoneGap plugin for iOS.

Skip: this optional for your to Create the PhoneGap project from the below. you create the project your style.

[building-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios-step-by-step](http://moduscreate.com/building-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios/)